# How to restore mysql database from mysql dump in IntelliJ IDEA 2018?

Tags: mysql, database, intellij-idea, path

I have MySQl Server, shell, workbench and connector ODBC installed. I want to restore database from mysql dump. I am stuck with option 'Path to mysql' in restore with mysql IDEA window. What should I choose?  Thanks in advance! 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is path to mysql.exe, like `C:\Soft\mysql-8.0.19-winx64\bin\mysql.exe`